# Using a preposition with the word 'grant'

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, prepositions, sentence-meaning

> **Obedience he had secured, and honor had been granted him**...

My question is why is it 'granted him' and not 'granted to him?'

Comment: The short version is that it's a construction similar to _I gave him my horse_. _I gave my horse to him_ is also correct and means the same thing, but the other format isn't necessarily wrong either.

Comment: Have you wondered why there is inversion in the first part: "Obedience he had secured," not "He had secured obedience?"

Comment: Yes and although grant works either way, don't you think the example comes from at least 500 years ago and possibly 1,000? That makes it barely comparable to modern English

Comment: In fact it comes from 1934: it's a quotation from the novella "Goodbye, Mr. Chips".  It was archaic even then, but far less so than, say, the King James Version of 1611.  A thousand years ago it would be "ġehīersumnesse he hæfþ ġeseald" (or possible ġeseald

Answer (score -1):

Both are acceptable.  Consider "I grant him my estate" and "I grant my estate to him".  Either sentence is fine.  The former has two direct objects and the latter has one direct object and one indirect object.  You're doing something similar to the first example, but in a passive voice.

Comment: Of course, but the question is why. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It’s a double accusative construction.  That’s part of English grammar.